# Error: 'Could not find module "< old-folder-name>" from "< path>"', after renaming angular folder

Tags: angular-cli

Renaming a folder that contains Angular project causes executing angular-cli commands like `ng serve` to show this error:

> Could not find module "< old-folder-name>" from "< path>".

Answer (score 0):

The project name has to be the same as the folder name. And it is saved in multiple files that have to be updated after renaming the folder. To find all those files search in the directory inside all files for your old-project-name and update all the occurrences. The most important places are in the following to files:

**File: `.angular-cli.json`**

```
{
    "project": {
        "name": "update-it-to-folde-name"
    }
...
}
```

**File: `package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "update-it-to-folde-name"
...
}
```